# Free RCS for Windows 7

Tags: version-control, windows-7

I've been using RCS (revision control system) from MKS Source Integrity for several old projects. I have to move to a new Windows 7 computer. The old version I have does not install on Windows 7, and a new version of the software is very expensive.

What is the best free or cheep source of RCS for Windows 7? Also, will it be compatible with MKS Toolkit which I am still going to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Git (MSysGit)](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) works on Windows 7 and is free. There is a learning curve associated with Git, which I think is worth it (for the benefits you get, especially regarding a distributed VCS), but some may disagree. This bundles come with `bash` and an `ssh` client (useful synchronization with remote repositories).

**EDIT:** For RCS specifically, there is an [RCS package](http://cygwin.com/packages/rcs/) via [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) or an independent package from the [Purdue RCS Homepage](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/RCS/) (the latter says "*The latest PC (OS/2 DOS Win95 NT)*", but I guess it might work on Windows 7, I'm fairly sure the Cygwin package works on Win 7).

Comment: I would prefer to stay with RCS since I have a number of scripts using it, and I am satisfied with its features (even though I realize it is considered obsolete).

Comment: Ah, in this case, [RCS in Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/packages/rcs/) might be an option.

Answer (score 4):

The official website for RCS has Windows 32-bit binaries, but they are dated. YMMV. http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/RCS/.

Edit: I just tried the binaries (from the first zip file). They seem to work on a trivial text file.

I put them in a directory. Then I created an "RCS" directory.  Then I created a text file. Then I ran "set TZ=EST" in my cmd.exe window (the tools require a timezone). Then I was able to check the text file in and out with the RCS command line tools.

Note that large files are probably not supported given the date of the binaries.

If you want the binaries to be available system wide, you have to place them in a location on your Windows PATH and set the TZ environmental variable to the zone you need in your account's environment.

Answer (score 1):

RCS offers reverse merge which can be useful when you want to apply selected fixes for ECO version of your software without addition on less tested product enhancements. I was able to produce ECO version of real-time control system with several hundred fixes without the assistance of software engineers working on the next release of the product. ClearCase did not offer similar capability at the time.

We used rcs and gmake. Build scripts were written in Perl. Each ran on native Windows. I wish the idiots at the software company in Washington would use / instead of \ for file separator.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 64-bit SETUP32.EXE fails "not compatible with the version of Windows you're running"

My workaround:

1. Copy sintcm32.dll from a 32-bit machine into c:\windows\syswow64.
2. In Explorer, double-click a .pj file, set description to "MKS Source Integrity Project/Sandbox File" and target to "[network location]\mkssi\mkssi32.exe"
3. Create start menu shortcuts to "[network location]\mkssi\mkssi32.exe" etc.